# Error NullPointerException al mostrar datos agregados en SQLite

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, sqlite

Buenos dias estimada comunidad, estoy trabajando una app con kotlin y sqlite, al momento de querer mostrar mis datos, me sale un error de NullPointerException que no se como solucionar.
Mi ID lo estoy haciendo autoincremental por lo que le paso null:

```
class preModel(
id: Int?,
campaign: String,
campus: String,
) {
var id: Int? = null;
var campaign: String = "";
var campus: String = "";

init {
    this.id = id;
    this.campaign = campaign;
    this.campus = campus;
}
}
```

Y al momento de hacer la inserción le envío null para que funcione el autoincrement:

```
                val status = crud?.insertPre(preModel(
                id = null, campaign = campaign, campus = campus))
            if(status > -1){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Pre registro agregado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                clearEditText()
            }
```

El proceso para que me muestre los datos es el siguiente:
Obtengo los datos con un onClickListener:

```
            override fun onClick(view: View, index: Int) {

            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, Update::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("idPre",listareo!!.get(index).id)
            startActivity(intent)

        }
```

Luego eso lo muestro:

```
    val index = intent.getStringExtra("idPre")

    crud = tareoCRUD(this)

    val listareo =crud?.getTareo(index)<-- Aqui me indica el error de NullPointerException

    id.setText(listareo!!.id.toString(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
    dni.setText(listareo!!.dni, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
    avance.setText(listareo!!.advance.toString(), 
    TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
```

Pero al momento de realizar la consulta individual de mis datos, me aparece el error NullPointerException:

```
    fun getTareo(id: String): preModel {
    var pre: preModel? = null

    val db:SQLiteDatabase = helper?.readableDatabase!!

    val columnas = arrayOf(tareoContract.Companion.Entrada.ID,
        tareoContract.Companion.Entrada.CAMPAIGN,
        tareoContract.Companion.Entrada.CAMPUS)

    val c:Cursor = db.query(
        tareoContract.Companion.Entrada.TBL_PRE,
        columnas,
        " idPre = ?",
        arrayOf(id),
        null,
        null,
        null
    )

    while(c.moveToNext()){
        pre = (preModel(
            c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(tareoContract.Companion.Entrada.ID)),
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(tareoContract.Companion.Entrada.CAMPAIGN)),
            c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(tareoContract.Companion.Entrada.CAMPUS))
        ))
    }
    c.close()

    return pre!!<--El error de NullPointerException me lo da en esta linea.
}
```

¿Alguien le a pasado lo mismo? O tenga alguna idea de como solucionar mi problema, de mi parte e intentado quitarle el null al id, pero no se como hacerlo autoincremental de otra forma y con tipo de dato TEXT en SQLite o String en Kotlin

Comment: Hola, en donde se muestra el error, que linea indica el  LogCat?

Comment: Acabo de editar mi consulta, le e estado haciendo seguimiento para ver que puede ser el error, y creo que en mi actividad donde recibo el ID del onClickListener es donde se encuentra el error, pero no se porque se ocaciona. Los errores estan marcados con <-- en la (val = listareo) y en (return pre!!)

Comment: Procura siempre incluir en tus preguntas, la traza de error, no sólo un resumen del mensaje.

Comment: Ok, los incluiré, gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Estimados, al momento de cambiar la variable index que recibe  val listareo =crud?.getTareo(index), por el un id cualquiera, ejemplo val listareo =crud?.getTareo("1") no me sale el error, y me lista el registro con ese id.

Comment: @Alfabravo acabo de ver el error, que no se origina en algún lugar señalado,al solucionar el nullPointerException me saltó otro error que me acerco a saber que es lo que lo ocasiona, pero sin saber como resolverlo, en este caso, modifico esta pregunta y la adapto a mi necesidad actual? ¿O elimino esta pregunta y creo una nueva?

Comment: Si es el mismo problema pero la traza de error cambiay el código a revisar es otro, yo editaría la pregunta. Si el problema es diferente, ya podría yo eliminar y comenzar de cero. Como prefieras :)

Comment: Perfectp @Alfabravo muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimada comunidad, vi dos errores que cometí, el primero:
Desde el onclick, el nombre que enviaba con putExtra era distinto que el que recibía en getStringExtra, lo causaba el nullPointerException, ya que no recibía valor alguno.
Estos dos deben llevar el mismo name, este codigo se encuentra donde se usa el LayoutManager

```
            override fun onClick(view: View, index: Int) {

        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, Update::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("idPre",listareo!!.get(index).id)<-- idPre es el name de putExtra que era distinto.
        startActivity(intent)

    }
```

Y aqui guardo el valor obtenido con putEXTRA en esta variable con getStringExtra, y debe tener el mismo name:
val index = intent.getStringExtra("idPre")<-- idPre

```
    crud = tareoCRUD(this)

    val listareo =crud?.getTareo(index)
```

Lo segundo, es que había definido en el modelo mi id con valor entero:

```
class preModel(
id: Int?,
activity: String,
advance: Int,

)
```

Y esta funcion solicitaba un String:

```
intent.putExtra("idPre",listareo!!.get(index).id)
```

Es el mismo putExtra que envía el id, lo solucione convirtiendo el id a String asi:

```
intent.putExtra("idPre",listareo!!.get(index).id.toString())
```

Y así solucioné mi error.